# Why is this program not finding the digit frequency correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

```
a = int(input())
digit = 0
count=0
temp = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    temp=a
    count = 0
    while(temp>0):
        digit = temp%10
        if digit == i:
         count+=1
        temp=temp/10
    if count>0:
      print(f'{i}\t{count}')
```

This program's output is always displayed as the last digit's frequency as one and doesn't give frequency of other digits.
Like if my input is 1991,
its output will be

```
1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the line `temp = temp/10`.

Take your example, `1991`. The division of this number by 10 is equal to `199.1`. In the next iteration when you take the mod (`%`), the result is `9.099999999999994`, which is not equal to any digit.

To fix it you can either **(i)** parse the division to int as `temp = int(temp/10)`, **(ii)** parse the digit to int as `digit = int(temp % 10)` or **(iii)** even better, perform the integer division `temp//10`, as stated by @mozway.

Then, you get the expected output:

```
1       2
9       2
```

Comment: To perform integer division `temp//10` is better. `temp%10` will always be an integer if integer input.

Comment: Yes, that is even better than parsing.

Comment: Yes thanks that fixed my problem. I used temp/10 because if we divide an integer by an integer i thought that i should get an integer as in java.

Comment: But i didnt understand that why was it giving output as 1   1

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code with better version.

In my code, I create a dictionary to store occurances of each digit: 1. find whether the digit is existed. Yes, then create a diction with count 1; else add 1 value to existing dictionary

```
a = input("Enter your number:")
str1 = str(a)
unique_number = {}
for each in str1:
    if(each not in unique_number):
        unique_number[each] = 1;
    else:
        unique_number[each] += 1;
        
for each in unique_number:
    print(unique_number[each])
```

Comment: I think using a string is defeating the purpose of this logic. Also you could then use directly `collections.Counter(a)` (a is already a string in your code)

Answer (score 0):

You have a single counter but potentially many values, plus you reset it for each number. Finally, the double loop if not needed and inefficient.

Here is a simple working code on the same logic. I am using here `collections.Counter` to hold the counts and a single loop with `divmod` to compute the integer division with remainder.

```
a=1991

from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

while a>0:
    a,r = divmod(a, 10)
    print(a,r)
    c[r]+=1

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({1: 2, 9: 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your code is `temp = temp/10`, In Python division result in floating point values where values always > 0. Use `temp = int(temp/10)`  this will fix your code and check other approach mentioned above.

Comment: integer division is more often performed as `temp // 10`.